# mkdir() is not setting chmod to 0777

Tags: php

Why does mkdir not set CHMOD to `0777`?

```
mkdir('/var/www/test', 0777);
```

After the dir is made the CHMOD is set to `0755`

from php.net

```
bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

the `$mode` should be `0777` by default... but if you leave the second argument empty the CHMOD still is set to `0755`

Comment: 0755 is the standard for user apache php!

Comment: This is a better question for http://s.tk/unix or http://s.tk/su.

Comment: Check out [`umask`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) `$old = umask(0); chmod("/path/some_dir/some_file.txt", 0755); umask($old);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://php.net/mkdir:

> Note: `mode` is ignored on Windows.
>
> The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change using [`umask()`](http://php.net/umask).

Answer (score 0):

Because it is influenced by the current [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). From the [PHP `mkdir` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

> The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change using umask().

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mkdir PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

> The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change
>   using umask().

Could this be the case?