# Need 775, 664 permissions for folders & files, getting stuck with 755 and 644 instead

Tags: php, apache, centos, centos6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mkdir() is not setting chmod to 0777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053341/mkdir-is-not-setting-chmod-to-0777)

I'm running a LAMP server and keep running into a file permission problem. I need to be able to programatically create directories with a permission of 775, and files with a permission of 664. I created a `www-pub` group and set ownership of `/var/www/html` to `root:www-pub` and I also `chmod 2775 /var/www` (as per the accepted answer for [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var).) However, when I create directories and files with PHP (running as user `apache`, which I added to group `www-pub`), the directories have a permission of 755 and the files 644.

My PHP code explicitly sets the permission to 775 (ex: `mkdir($someDir, 0775)` but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

However, when I connect through SFTP (as a different user than `apache`, but still a member of `www-group`), I can create dirs as 775 and files as 664.

How can I make sure that dirs and files are created with the proper permissions?

Note: I'm running CentOS 6

Comment: Worth looking into whether PHP or Apache are setting the umask.

Comment: @Arms: Per user comments on `mkdir` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php), have you tried `umask(0)` before creating the directory?  Failing that, what PHP version is running, is "safe mode" on, and what are the permissions of the parent directory?